# Concatenating dataframes generates NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

pandas concat show NaN.
Now my codes is

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("Desktop/t.csv")
df_train.head()
df_train_y = pd.read_csv("Desktop/z.csv")
df_train_y.head()
csv_data = pd.concat([df_train, df_train_y])
csv_data.head(50)
```

When I run it,
column is like
[colum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6toO.png)

So,NaN is shown.
When I did `df_train.head()`&`df_train_y`,all data is shown.
To fix this,should I use DataFrame?
I wanna load data from csv directory, but is it impossible?
How can I fix this?

Comment: `pd.concat([df_train, df_train_y],axis=1)` try this ?

Comment: @Wen it works!!thx!!

Comment: Glad it help ~!